# gradle: create several wars

Tags: jakarta-ee, gradle

I've a simple gradle script like that:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

webAppDirName = 'WebContent'

repositories {
     mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version:'7.0'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.ogm', name: 'hibernate-ogm-mongodb', version: '4.2.0.Final'
    compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '1.1.0.Final'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-json-provider', version: '2.5.3'
    compile group: 'com.hubspot.jackson', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-propertyfiltering', version: '0.7.0'

    compile project(':swiller_lib')
}
```

I would like to generate several wars:

1. Full (for example, with logging)
2. Without logging (excluding some dependencies)
3. Excluding some java source.
4. Without JPA (without persistence.xml file)

Basicly, I would need to generate several wars excluding some dependencies and excluding java source files (creating deveral source sets... (I supouse))

Could you tell how to do that?
I'm figuring out that it's must be easy, but I'm a little clumsy now...

Thanks for all.

Comment: Isn't it what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077694/create-multiple-war-files-with-different-dependencies-in-gradle ?

Comment: Yes, looks like the same question to me, too. The answer would definitely involve creating several task of the type War.