# Can there be multiple war tasks in build.gradle to generate multiple wars with different dependencies

Tags: gradle

I am trying to do similar thing as: [Create multiple .WAR files with different dependencies in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077694/create-multiple-war-files-with-different-dependencies-in-gradle)

But the solution given in this post is not working. I am using gradle 2.5 to achieve this.

Expectation is to generate 3 different wars as output of the script. I created a simplest project with minimal dependencies. When i execute build.gradle, it just gives me single war named: Test-1.0.war. Test is name of the sample project i created.

Here is build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'

task createStandardWar(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
    baseName = 'standard'
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/libs")
    classifier = 'Functional'
}

task createStandardWarQasOnly(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
    baseName = 'standard-qas-only'
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/libs")
    classifier = 'Functional2'
}

task createStandardWarQasAndLog4J(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
    baseName = 'standard-qas-log4j'
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/libs")
    classifier = 'Functional3'
}

task createDists(dependsOn: [createStandardWar, createStandardWarQasOnly, createStandardWarQasAndLog4J])

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}
```

Comment: Define "is not working". What task do you execute, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: Build.gradle executes successfully but expectation is to have 3 wars. What i get is just one with name standard-qas-log4j-Functional3.war

Comment: Pls ignore my last comment. Output the build.gradle is Test-1.0.war. Expectation is to have 3 different wars as named in the script. Test is the sample project i created to achieve this behavior.

Comment: Answer my question: What task do you execute?

Comment: That was the mistake i was making. I was executing gradle clean build and not "gradle clean createDists". Thanks for pointing that out. It is working now.